# Find the limit of $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,\pi/2)} \cos x \sin y$ and prove that your result is correct.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit and prove that your result is correct.

$$\lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,\pi/2)} \cos x \sin y$$

**My trial:**

I have calculated the limit by direct substitution and I found that it is 1. but I have a difficulty in proving this. I know that I should start with the inequality $$|\cos x \sin y -1|< \epsilon$$ and try to isolate the inequalities $|x|$ &$|y-\pi/2|$ from it in order to use that $|x| < \delta$ &$|y-\pi/2| < \delta$ ...... am I correct in my understanding? If so I do not know how to do this ...... could anyone help me please?

Comment: Product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: May be he has to prove it from $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition ? @saulspatz

Comment: @nicomezi Maybe so.  That why my comment is a question.

Comment: yes I have to prove it through $\epsilon - \delta$ definition @saulspatz

Comment: yes I have to prove it through $\epsilon - \delta$ definition @nicomezi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x):=$

$|\cos x \sin y -\cos x +\cos x -1| \le$

$|\cos x (\sin y -1)| + |\cos x -1| \le$

$ |\sin y-1| +|\cos x-1| .$

$d:= ((x^2+(y-π/2)^2)^{1/2}.$

Since $\cos x$ , $\sin  y$ are continuos:

For $\epsilon/2$ there is a $\delta_1$ s.t.

$|x| \lt \delta_1$  implies

$|\cos x -1| \lt \epsilon/2.$

For $\epsilon/2$ there is a $\delta_2$ s.t.

$|y-π/2| \lt \delta_2$  implies

$|\sin y -1| \lt \epsilon/2;$

Choose $\delta =\min (\delta_1, \delta_2)$ .

Then

$ (x^2+(y-π/2)^2)^{1/2} \lt \delta $

implies

$f(x) \lt |\sin y-1| +|\cos x -1| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Can we say that $\delta = \min (1, \epsilon)$ ..... or this will be incorrect?

Comment: I am convinced with your solution ..... I am just asking you because this was how it solved in the class ..... so I was just wondering if there is another solution that leads to this delta?

Comment: hopefully.You can solve this problem differently.Go through the solution done in class and verify each step. Do not know what your teacher did.

Comment: it is not my teacher it was one of my colleges and I wrote only the final answer.

Comment: hopefully.Different approaches can give different expressions for delta. What you need to show: For epsilon ,given, there is a delta . Again you can get different deltas by choosing different paths.You need to go through the calculation if your colleague , the answer by itself tells you little.If his derivation is ok, fine.

Answer (score 1):

$| \cos x \sin y -1|= |\cos x \sin y-\cos x \sin( \pi /2)+\cos x \sin( \pi /2) - \sin( \pi/2)| $

$\le| \cos x| \cdot| \sin y - \sin (\pi/2)|+| \cos x-1|.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I also want to know if my understanding I mentioned in the question correct or no .... could you please look at it?

Comment: you mean that $|\cos x -1| < \delta$, and $|\sin y -1| < \delta$? If so then my understanding mentioned in the question above was wrong.

Comment: yes after what you wrote I will write $ < | y -\pi/2|+|x| < 2\delta$ then $\delta = \epsilon /2$ ...... correct?